# Fetch fans from a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, this is my scenario: I have to fetch all the fans from a Facebook Page, but the Graph API don't have any method to do this.

I searched whole Google and Stack Overflow and found a [bug report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12880) where everyone saying it existed but Facebook discontinued for some problems. They are trying to fix, but no good news so far.

Then an (obvious) idea came to me: what about building a crawler to fetch the fans?

Anyone have an idea if Facebook allow this kind of information access? At least, until they fix the API.

Answer (score 2):

The condition part of a FQL must contains an indexed field.

Here `uid` is the indexed field of the `page_fan` table. So we can't retrieve the data without using it.

```
SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=USER_ID
```

The above query only provides the ID of the page the user had liked.

After the detailed search for retrieving the fans details, I reached the conclusion that Facebook does not provide the fan's details because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the Graph API, you just have to use another method for this matter. The solution is called FQL.

Facebook has a table called `page_fan` (docs [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/)) which you can use to find users who liked of a page fan (fans).

Let's take for example the page of The Coca Cola company. This page has the id `40796308305`. The query to get all the ids of fans of this page is:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=40796308305
```

Of course, you will need a valid acces_token to use this in your application. If you want to test live this query, use the following url:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=40796308305&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried this FQL, but page_id isn't an indexable field, only uid as shown in docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/

Comment: The example was tested before I posted. So double check what you have tried ;)

Comment: "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql "

Tried with the URL you posted, facebook return this error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this may have worked, but no longer does due to the un-indexed place_id `<error_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd">
<error_code>604</error_code>
<error_msg>
Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql
</error_msg>`

Comment: yes, you are right. for the last year facebook has changed the way this table worked

Answer (score 0):

This used to work using FQL like misterjinx posted but unfortunately no longer works and is not available with the Facebook graph api.  There are lots of people commenting about it on the [page_fan documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) page but no solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for page_fan

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+uid+from+page_fan+where+uid=732484576+and+page_id=171535666239724&access_token=135669679827333|siKaemNLpHRDuJVnUPeChZYko6c
```

> Returns True each time.

Answer (score -3):

A bit late, but if you havent found the solution, all you need to do is get the number from 
http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

change cocacola for the facebook ID you want to collect fans for.

Comment: This returns the raw count of likes but not the individual fans themselves.